# How to include clickable link in an Android switch label?

Tags: android

My app has a Switch control with a label of "I agree to the Terms and Conditions".

How can I style **Terms and Conditions** (and not the rest) like a link (blue and underlined) and detect when it is clicked so I can either:

a. open a URL in the web browser, or

b. pop a new fragment onto the stack?

Comment: If your issue is resolved, you may accept an answer that helped you, or post your own answer if you solved it in a better way...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) class.

Here is the example:

```
String termsAndConditions = "I agree to the Terms and Conditions";

SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(termsAndConditions);

int tIndex = signUpText.indexOf('T');

spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), tIndex, termsAndConditions.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

textView.setText(spannableString);
```

Note: the above example makes the "Terms and Conditions" part into blue color

Also in order make your part of the text clickable, use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) class

**EDIT:**

```
mSwitchTermsAndConditions = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_terms_and_conditions);
    mTermsAndConditions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.terms_and_conditions);

    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("I agree to the Terms and Conditions");

    ClickableSpan linkSpan=new ClickableSpan(){

        @Override public void onClick(View widget){

            //open fragment or webview
        }
        @Override public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds){
            ds.setUnderlineText(true);
            ds.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    };

    String s = "I agree to the Terms and Conditions";

    int tIndex = s.indexOf('T');

    spannableString.setSpan(linkSpan, tIndex, s.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    mTermsAndConditions.setText(spannableString);
    mTermsAndConditions.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    mSwitchTermsAndConditions.setChecked(false);
```

**XML:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch_terms_and_conditions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/terms_and_conditions"
    android:text="I agree to the Terms and Conditions" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Thanks, SpannableString looks great! I haven't figured out how to make it work with the label text of a Switch though. Your answer and all the others are about TextView, not Switch.

Comment: What is the exact problem that you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Linkify` class to make text in your views work as links.

The post [Linkify your Text!](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html) shows how to get it working.

The basic web links work directly to open a URL in a web browser, whereas if you want to start another `Activity` or something like that, you'll need to play with the `scheme` defined in the intent filters of your activity.

For example, you can put up a link in the text of your view which would cover **Terms and Conditions** like:

```
TextView lblTerms = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblTerms);
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("Terms and Conditions");
String link = "com.example.myapp://showTermsAndCondition";
Linkify.addLinks(lblTerms, myPattern, link);
```

and this will require your intent filter of the target activity to be something like:

```
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="com.example.myapp" />  
</intent-filter>
```

Now when you Linkify it, it should open up you target activity.

Answer (score 0):

Handle click using ClickableSpan

```
ClickableSpan policyClick = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                    openPopUp();
               }

            }
        };
```

Set ClickableSpan  to SpannableString

```
String text = "I agree to the Terms and Conditions";
SpannableString policyText = new SpannableString(text);
                policyText.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, text.length(), 0);
                policyText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, text.length(), 0);
                textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                textView.setText(policyText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```